# Can not authorize with userDetailsService

Tags: spring-security

I am learning Spring Security, this is my configure class, very simple:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/")
                  .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users")
                  .hasRole("isAdmin")
                .antMatchers("/articles")
                  .hasRole("isUser")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                  .permitAll();
    }
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService  {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> simpleGrantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        simpleGrantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("isUser"));
        return new User(username, "{noop}123456", simpleGrantedAuthorities);

    }
}
```

From this configuration, that I allow anyone to login with any username and a certain password `123456`, and I give each user `isUser` roles.

I wish anyone can login with any username and get permit to access `/articles`.

But unfortunately, when I try to login, yeah, login is successful, but failed to access to `/articles`.

I can not find the reason, I think already give the user permission, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in javadoc of `hasRole` method ([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.11.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#hasRole-java.lang.String-)):

> Shortcut for specifying URLs require a particular role. If you do not
>   want to have "ROLE_" automatically inserted see hasAuthority(String).
>
> Parameters: role - the role to require (i.e. USER, ADMIN, etc). Note,
>   it should not start with "ROLE_" as this is automatically inserted.

Thus, either add `ROLE_` prefix to your role `isUser`, or use `hasAuthority` method instead of `hasRole`.